# Unix copying script automatically copy files with same name

Tags: unix

I have a simple Unix script that copies files from a number of directories and dumps them all into one directory.  Because I am copying thousands of files, I’ve run into the case where some files have the same name.

When this occurs instead of copying the file, Unix gives me an error.  I assume this is because it can not overwrite the existing file.

```
cp: cannot create [pathname]: Permission denied
```

What I want to do, is have Unix automatically create a second file, perhaps by appending (2) on the filename like windows, without overwriting the one that already exists.  I’ve looked through the CP option list trying to find an option that will give me what I need, but nothing is jumping out.  Any ideas?

Hopefully I am missing something obvious, since I’ve never written a Unix script before.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I’m honestly not sure which version I am working with.  If you can tell me how to check I will.

Code Excerpt:

```
cp /vob/application/spottool/custom/*.kl ~/Sourcefiles
```

Answer (score 2):

Which flavor of Unix are you working on? GNU cp, as used on Linux, has

```
cp --backup=numbered src1/* src2/* dest/
```

Comment: I received an illegal options when trying `–backup=numbered`

Comment: Are you using GNU cp? (Try `cp --version`.) If yes, make sure to use two dashes, you only typed one in your comment.

Comment: `cp --version` gives me another illegal option

Comment: I.e., you're not using GNU cp. You might be able to compile GNU coreutils (the package containing cp) for your system, or your local cp or mv might have a similar option, although the latter I doubt.